# Is Redis Hash Hmset executed in Transaction?

Tags: redis, transactions

Suppose I am using `HMSET myhash field1 "Hello" field2 "World"` to set two fields in my redis, and some others are using `HGETALL key` to get all keys, In this case do they have the chance to get the result `field1`? or the result may only be either null or `field1, field2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis guarantees that both `HMSET` and `HGETALL` are executed atomically. So you'll either get null reply or all fields of `myhash`.